# Accessing GraphDB Workbench throught the internet (not localhost) in a Nginx server

Tags: nginx, server, sparql, rdf, graphdb

I have GraphDb (standlone server version) in Ubuntu Server 16 running in localhost (with the command ./graphdb -d in /etc/graphdb/bin). But I only have ssh access to the server in the terminal, can't open Worbench in localhost:7200 locally.

I have many websites running on this machine with Ningx. If I try to access the machine's main IP with the port 7200 through the external web it doesn't work (e.g. http://193.133.16.72:7200/ = "connection timmed out").

I have tried to make a reverse proxy with Nginx with this code ("xxx" = domain):

```
  listen 7200;
  listen [::]:7200;
  server_name sparql.xxx.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7200;
  }
}
```

But all this fails. I checked and port 7200 is open in firewall (ufw). In the logs I get info that GraphDB is working locally in some testes. But I need Workbench access to import and create repositories (not sure how to do it or if it is possible without the Workbench GUI).

Is there a way to connect through the external web to the Workbench using a domain/IP and/or Nginx?

Read all the documentation and searched all day, but could not find a way to deal with this sorry. I only used GraphDB locally (the simple installer version), never used the standalone server in production before, sorry.

PS: two extra questions related: 
a) For creating an URI endpoint it is the same procedure? 
b) For GraphDB daemon to start automattically at boot time (with the command ./graphdb -d in graph/bin folder), what is the recommended way and configuration? (tryed the line "/etc/graphdb/bin ./graphdb -d" in rc.local but it didn't worked).

Answer (score 3):

In case it is usefull for someone, I was able to make it work with this Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sparql.xxxxxx.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7200;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

I think it was the "proxy_set_header Host $host;" that solved it (tried the rest without it before and didn't worked). I think GraphDB uses some headers to set configurations, and they were not passing.

I wounder if I am forgetting something else important to forward in the proxy, but in this moment the Worbench seams to work and opens in the domain used "sparql.xxxxxx.com".